# GDB target exec

Tags: debugging, gdb, target

I would like to use avr-gdb with a file elf
Precisely I need to target a file in windows.
I tried this:

```
target exec C:/Users/DARKCO1/AppData/Local/Temp/build8029591154609303866.tmp/sketch_aug17a.elf
```

But I get "No such file or directory"

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you try backslashes?

Comment: Yes, I did it. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The were two problems:

1) the backslashes

2) I believe the ~ because I changed paths of the folder containing the elf and gdb didn't give me the error.

Answer (score 0):

Paths in Windows use backslashes. Recode the path as

```
C:\Users\DARKCO1\AppData\Local\Temp\build8029591154609303866.tmp\sketch_aug17a.elf
```